# Getting data into a telerik control using a static SQL connection

Tags: c#, sql, telerik

I am trying to populate this telerik dropdownbutton control with data I acquired from a SQL data source. I use a c# file to handle the database connection and I made Item a static class. Item is the field I want to populate the dropdownbutton with. I have done about everything I know to do and done I am at wits end with this. I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult to implement.

Here is where I am trying to load the data into the button. I am not sure what to put after .Add(.

```
public Label Item { get; set; }

    public VersionEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        rddBtnPreviousFormat.Items.Add("what goes here?")
    }
```

Here is how I am calling my data source.

```
 private Label()
    {
        SqlConnection dbConn = null;
        List<Item> listID = new List<Item>();

        try
        {
            using (dbConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXXXXX"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT FormatID, FormatName FROM dbo.TrayLabelFormat";

                SqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                dbConn.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Item l = new Item();
                        l.FormatID = reader.GetInt32(1);
                        l.FormatName = reader.GetString(0);
                        listID.Add(l);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
        return;
    }
}

class Item
{
    public Item()
    { }

    public int FormatID { get; set; }
    public string FormatName { get; set; }
}
```

It's probably as simple as a naming error I just can't find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I might have missed this, but what datatype is `rddBtnPreviousFormat`?

Comment: @gunr2171 It's not a data type it's a basically a cross between a button and a list box

Comment: Then what is `rddBtnPreviousFormat.Items`? What is it a collection of?

Comment: @gunr2171 you use .Items.Add to populate the field with the data. It doesn't care what format it is in.

Comment: _"It doesn't care what format it is in"_ Then what is the problem? It should take your class, I guess. If it needs some way to display it, try overriding `ToString` in your `Item` class.

Comment: @gunr2171 the problem is what goes after the ".Add(" I have seen references where they use for example. Item newItem = new Item(); then they declare after .Add(newItem.Name, newItem.Num) and it works. I can't get mine to work.